# How to know if a List Element in OpenUI5 is ctrl-clicked or shift-clicked?

Tags: list, event-handling, mouseevent, sapui5, ctrl

The event that is sent to the itemPress handler is not a mouse event but a specific sap itemPress event. I didn't find how to get the state of the ctrlKey out of this event object.

The view:

```
<List showSeparators="None" items="..." id="browserList" itemPress="onEntityPress" />
```

The handler:

```
Controller.prototype.onEntityPress = function (event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) { // => undefined property
    // do something
  }
}
```

I didn't find information about that on my research on the web.
Please, has someone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never checked the UI5 events to that degree but mouse events never send a keyboard key code regardless of the framework (or vanilla). I suppose you could check them independently though. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I simply want to execute different actions weather the ctrlKey was pressed while the List Element was clicked.

Comment: @Ch.Kuhn Was the intention to implement range selection (Shift + mouse click)? In that case, it's now supported out-of-the-box since UI5 1.69 [(commit)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/4b5d590c8d478565c8b7467a0f262a1456bb445c). Otherwise, I'm afraid you'll have to extend the List control in order to expose the key press event to the application

Answer (score 0):

Kuhn

Here is one way to achieve this

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>App Title</title>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
        </script>
      <script>
      sap.ui.define(["sap/m/List", "sap/m/StandardListItem", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"],
                  function(List, StandardListItem, JSONModel) {
      "use strict";

      List.extend("MyList", {
        metadata: {
          events: {
            ctrlClick: {},
            shiftClick: {}
          }
        },
        renderer: {}
      });

      StandardListItem.extend("MyItem", {
        renderer: {},
        onAfterRendering: function() {
          var that = this;
          var oList = this.getParent();
          var cntrlIsPressed = false;
          var shiftIsPressed = false;

          if (StandardListItem.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
            StandardListItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
            var $this = this.$();
            $this.keydown(function(event) {
              cntrlIsPressed = (event.which === 17);
              shiftIsPressed = (event.which === 16);
            });
            $this.keyup(function() {
              cntrlIsPressed = false;
              shiftIsPressed = false;
            });
            $this.click(function(event) {
              if (cntrlIsPressed) {
                oList.fireCtrlClick({
                  item: that
                })
              } else if (shiftIsPressed) {
                oList.fireShiftClick({
                  item: that
                })
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });

      var oList = new MyList({
        items: {
          path: "/items",
          template: new MyItem({
            title: "{name}"
          })
        },
        shiftClick: function(oEvent) {
          console.log(oEvent.getParameter("item"));
        }
      });

      oList.setModel(new JSONModel({
        items: [
          {name: "abc" }
        ]
      }));

      oList.placeAt('content');
    });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

http://jsbin.com/jegehobehi/edit?html,output